# $_SESSION variables lost during OAuth callback

Tags: redirect, cookies, session, oauth

When I attempt an OAuth handshake, the first step is a **GET** call to obtain an access code like so.

```
# Redirect to request authorization code
$url = $this->get_authorization_url();
header("Location: $url");
exit;
```

Just before I send this I store the current URL in a **$_SESSION['last_url']** variable so that after authentication is complete I can redirect it back to the page the user originally attempted.

This authorization url uses the client id and secret to obtain an access code which is then returned to my callback script. The problem is the moment I land on my callback page the **$_SESSION** is completely blank. I need to ensure I can get this original URL to the end of the handshake and after an entire day devoted to this I'm desperate for some answers.

**NOTE:** Also should be noted that this site is hosted on WordPress Engine which has a strong caching mechanism which could be a cause of this problem, but even if it is I need a solution around it.

Comment: Did you use `session_start()` in your code? Also, have you read https://wpengine.com/support/cookies-and-php-sessions/? As that article suggests, storing your data in the database would be a good alternative to PHP sessions.

Comment: how is this wordpress specific? In general sessions should never be used,

Comment: If I store this in the database as a transient how would I know what to retrieve from the callback perspective? It's going to come back with a `code` and no details as to who's session this code belongs to. And yes I have `start_session()` included.

Comment: a lot of WP hosts don't support PHP session variables, particularly WP Engine. It's also incompatible with most caching mechanisms